# (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RasterCount') AND (ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes..)

Tags: python, github, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a GitHub code. But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/Code/inference.py", line 127, in <module>
    main(config, args)
  File "/content/Code/inference.py", line 76, in main
    'inference_data_loader', module_data, image_path, district)
  File "/content/Code/parse_config.py", line 103, in init_obj
    return getattr(module, module_name)(*args, **module_args)
  File "/content/Code/data_loader/data_loaders.py", line 79, in __init__
    transformation=transforms)
  File "/content/Code/base/base_dataset.py", line 127, in __init__
    x+1).ReadAsArray() for x in range(image_ds.RasterCount)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'
```

I suppose this is tracing back to this line of code:

```
image_ds = gdal.Open(image_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
all_raster_bands = [image_ds.GetRasterBand(x+1).ReadAsArray() for x in range(image_ds.RasterCount)]
```

But I have checked and `image_path` points towards a valid path.
Why is this error showing?

I re-ran the same command and now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/Code/inference.py", line 127, in <module>
    main(config, args)
  File "/content/Code/inference.py", line 76, in main
    'inference_data_loader', module_data, image_path, district)
  File "/content/Code/parse_config.py", line 103, in init_obj
    return getattr(module, module_name)(*args, **module_args)
  File "/content/Code/data_loader/data_loaders.py", line 79, in __init__
    transformation=transforms)
  File "/content/Code/base/base_dataset.py", line 131, in __init__
    district=district, this_landsat8_bands_list=all_raster_bands)
  File "/content/Code/base/datagen.py", line 88, in mask_landsat8_image_using_rasterized_shapefile
    clipped_full_spectrum.append(np.multiply(this_band, shapefile_mask))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2472,2490) (2061,2075)
```

I suppose this is tracing back to this line of code:

```
for idx, this_band in enumerate(this_landsat8_bands_list):
        print("{}: Band-{} Size: {}".format(district, idx, this_band.shape))
        clipped_full_spectrum.append(np.multiply(this_band, shapefile_mask))
```

I tried to change `np.multiply` to `np.dot` but still getting the same error.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'` means that `gdal.Open(image_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)` failed (even though `image_path` it's a valid path), so when you call `image_ds.RasterCount` you are actually calling `None.RasterCount`, which is invalid

Comment: For the second error we cannot help you without further informations about the array you are using

Comment: @YuriC So, how can I resolve the first error in this case, then? The confusing thing here is that I am getting the second error when I re-run the same command without changing anything. How is the second error linked to the first error?

Comment: @YuriC I have edited the question and provided the line of code for the second error.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know `gdal`. According to https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html?highlight=open#osgeo.gdal.Open, you don't need to write `gdal.GA_ReadOnly` because it's default. I don't know why you are getting two dfferent errors when you rerun, it seems odd. Maybe the error is caused not from the second line `all_raster_bands = ...` but somewhere above of that. To know if the line `image_ds = ...` has been executed correctly you can add this line after that `if image_ds: print("First line correctly executed")`

Comment: From the documentation of `np.multiply` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) "If x1.shape != x2.shape, they must be broadcastable to a common shape (which becomes the shape of the output)." So the second error is due to you trying to multiply two different shaped np.arrays. That is a math error and not a coding error

Comment: @YuriC It's printing this line of code.

Comment: Nice, so `image_ds` is not `None` and `gdal.Open` has not failed. I don't know how to help you with the second error. The two np.arrays must have equal shape to be able to `np.multiply` them

Comment: Yes, the two arrays must be of the same size for 'np.multiply' but I don't know how to solve this error in this case. As stated above I have tried np.dot as well.

Comment: Those are two different functions, that do different things. `np.multiply` permorms the Hadamard product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) while `np.dot` permorms the usual matrix product. For `multiply` the two shapes must be (n,m) and (n,m), while for `dot` the shapes must be (n1,m) and (m, n2). You have (2472,2490) and (2061,2075) so both functions can't be used. Again, this is not a coding problem. You should understand what those matrices are, why they have the shape they have and decide the function to use depending on what you have to do

Comment: @YuriC Got it! Let me work on this. I'll get back to you if something works.